# Can you use two where conditions in an assign Liquid tag?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

Can you use two [`where`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/where/) conditions in an [`assign`](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/variable/) Liquid tag?

I'm getting this build error when trying to `bundle exec jekyll serve --trace`:

```
Liquid Exception: Liquid error (line 7): wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 3) in party/democratic/index.md
             Error: Liquid error (line 7): wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 3)
```

This is the Liquid tag in question:

```
{% assign people = site.data.people |  where: election_2020.office, 'U.S. President' and election_2020.party, 'Democratic' | sort: 'last_names' %}
```

I can't find documentation one way or the other whether you can have two `where` filters in an `assign` tag.

PS: here's a sample of the `people.yml` file:

```
-
  id: 'julian-castro'
  first_names: 'Julián'
  last_names: 'Castro'
  full_name: 'Julián Castro'
  image: '/images/people/julian-castro-wikipedia.jpg'
  gender: 'male'
  image: '/images/people/julian-castro-wikipedia.jpg'
  election_2020:
    office: 'U.S. President'
    address: 'P.O. Box 501'
    latitude: '29.430018'
    longitude: '-98.4987548'
    city: 'San Antonio'
    state: 'TX'
    zip: '78292'
    donate: 'https://secure.actblue.com/donate/julianforthefuture'
    facebook: 'https://www.facebook.com/julianforthefuture/'
    instagram: 'https://www.instagram.com/juliancastrotx/?hl=en'
    twitter: 'https://twitter.com/JulianCastro'
    website: 'https://www.julianforthefuture.com/'
    party: 'Democratic'
    election_type: 'primary'
    source: 'https://voteinfo.utah.gov/2020-presidential-candidates/'
    candidate_status: 'withdrew'
  last_updated: '2020-02-20'
```

Comment: PS: I am currently pulling in all `office: 'U.S. President'` on https://www.electionsutah.org/office/us-president/ but I'd like to filter those results down only to `party: 'Democratic'` on https://www.electionsutah.org/party/democratic

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where filter allows only to compare a key value with another value. If you want to use complex filtering you can use [where_exp](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/#binary-operators-in-where_exp-filter40) filter.

```
{% assign people = site.data.people | where_exp: "someone", "someone.election_2020.office == 'U.S. President' and someone.election_2020.party == 'Democratic'" | sort: "last_names" %}
```

Comment: Ah! I see! Thank you so much! This has been killing me!